# Error while updb, how to debug it?

Tags: 9, updating

I've updated opigno_lms to 2.29 version without any problems by composer and then "drush updb", then installed 3.0.2 version through composer, but "drush updb" gives me:

> [notice] Update started: opigno_statistics_update_9001
> [error]  Argument 2 passed to Drupal\Core\Config\CachedStorage::write() must be of the type array, bool given, called in /home/mine/praca/gitowanie/opigno_project/web/modules/contrib/opigno_statistics/opigno_statistics.install on line 83
> [error]  Update failed: opigno_statistics_update_9001

Anybody has solution for that? Or idea how to debug it? Every other update goes nice, but this one breaks everything... I tried already plenty of times, but it fails all the time, on 2 different servers.

Answer (score 3):

If you look for a way to effectively debug `updb`, then try to use Xdebug. If you have problems configuring it for command line scripts, you can always run updates via `update.php` in your browser.

When you set a breakpoint on `opigno_statistics_update_9001`, you will see exactly where the faulty argument comes from.